# Не понимаю this, static

Tags: java, static, this

Как новичок испытываю проблемы в создании классов в которых используется this. Попробую объяснить ... Вот я создаю новый класс Visualfile который принадлежит MainActivity (значит добавляю в нём - extends MainActivity). В новом классе создаю метод - public static void visualfile(). Что бы переменные в MainActivity использовались и в новом классе (обязательное условие!) прописываю их в MainActivity как public static. И всё всегда работает прекрасно, но не в тех случаях, когда в методе нового класса используется this, ну, например, MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,  в таком случаи выдаётся ошибка и мне студия предлагает сделать его НЕ static. Ну хорошо, не ststic так не static, но теперь то ошибочен вызов моего метода Visualfile.visualfile(); из MainActivity. Порочный круг! Я прописывал в методе нового класса и null: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(null,   и ничего не подчёркивалось красным, но при вызове метода приложение вылетает. Подскажите, что делать то? Про this я конечно почитал, но в конкретном случаи мне это мало помогло.

Comment: Если не секрет, по каким учебникам вы изучали Java и Android?

Comment: Обращаться к полям активити извне через static дурная идея, от которой следует немедленно отказаться. Так же стоит прямо сейчас начать читать учебник по андроид-разработке

Comment: Если посмотреть документацию, то метод scanFile() первым аргументом принимает Context. Класс Activity  является наследником  контекста, поэтому в активити мы можем вместо контекста указать this. В прочих классах мы тоже можем указать this, но они не наследники контекста и работать ничего не будет. В таких случаях контекст должен быть указан явно и получен от того класса, который имеет его "живой" экземпляр, то есть какой-нибудь new Context здесь не прокатит

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, не секрет. Delphi, C++ изучал по книжкам, а java не читаю и не буду. Потому, что я четко осознал, что никогда не пойму маразма, например, почему для включения фонарика нужно ~70(!) строк кода вместо простого lighter.on, А Callback в процедуре упоминается 11(!) раз. Что бы его понять нужно стать Колбеком Колбековичем Колбакяном =) И так всё! Мне нужно сделать 3 программы. От безысходности я применяю чудный метод: беру кусок кода и по разному впендюриваю его пока не заработает. Дивно, но результат прекрасен и стабилен. Но вы даже не представляете себе, что это за программы!

Comment: Какой прекрасный и стабильный результат вы получаете, отлично видно по вашему вопросу - это дно. Представить, какие "прекрасные" программы из этого получаются тоже не трудно. Продолжайте "по разному впендюривать" , есть мнение, что и обезьяны когда то напишут "войну и мир", если будут просто долбить по клавишам. У вас тоже когда-нибудь получится

Comment: pavlofff,   «Спасибо, сэр, ха-ха» «батут работает»  =)    дно - это когда человек зазнаётся превращаясь в упомянутую вами обезъяну. Вам ничего не видно т.к. реальный результат  видели только в своём надменном воображении. К моему огромному счастью мысли других людей никак не влияют на прекрасный (хоть головой об стену) результат.  Хотя это не имеет ни какого значения. (На сайте есть возможность пожаловаться мамочке) Желаю вам хорошего дня и весёлостей! )

Answer (score 2):

static методы не могут ссылаться на this, т.к. статики не знают про объект класса, более того они загружаются класслоадреом еще до того, как любой объект будет создан.
Когда ты в методе MediaScannerConnection.scanFile используешь this, это просто не имеет смысла.
Попробуй вместо использования this передавать то, что тебе нужно через аргумент метода. Например библиотека статических методов Math: Math.max(19, 123); Все, что необходимо методу приходит к нему через аргументы.
Если ты сделал метод не статическим, то для вызова метода тебе понадобиться какой-то конкретный объект, так создай его перед вызовом:

```
MediaScannerConnection conn = new MediaScannerConnection();
conn.scanFiles(whatEver);
```

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java#staticm вот хорошая статья для понимания статиков